# Best practices on migrating to Angular Material MDC?

Tags: angular, user-interface, sass, angular-material, mdc

It feels like Angular Material MDC introduces quite a few "breaking" changes for UIs but I haven't been able to find a detailed enough migration guide (mainly for the **SCSS side of things**) on what exactly to do after the automated migration tool has been run.

For example:

- It seems that `--mat-mdc-*` variables are now used all over the place but I cannot find anywhere in the official guides the exact lists of such variables
- Also, it seems that for button labels and checkboxes (and probably more components) it disregards the contrast colors defined in the palette and applies by default a high contrast colour calculated by Material. The docs do not seem to mention best practice on how to override this default behaviour. As a result we're having to override on a component by component basis which doesn't feel right.

Angular publishes some guides that in theory talk about this topic, but again they don't seem enough to carry you through a successful and relatively seamless migration.